# SQL Server stored procedure long running intermittently

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 5 stored procedures, called by an api, that run in under 100 ms normally, but intermittently, all the stored procedures suddenly take > 10 seconds in production. We did stress test before going live and it was all good during stress test.

For each of the stored procedures, I capture start time using `SYSDATETIME()` and log it an table at the end of the stored procedure with end time as well.  So I run profiler on production and notice strange things.

For example, today, profiler RPC:completed event start time is 09:18:04.680 where as my stored procedure execution log tables says the execution started at 09:19:54.288. So there is a 110second mismatch between profiler execution start vs my stored procedure internal start time. So this happens to all stored procedures for a window of 2-3mins and everything clears by itself.

I've ran perfmon and nothing shows out of ordinary to me. The SQL Server has high capacity with the application only running few users currently so not a very high traffic application.

I also have Redgate SQL Monitor and it doesn't show any abnormal wait times.

I'm not even sure where to look for. I'm not sure its parameter sniffing because one of the stored procedure affected doesn't accept any parameters. After the 2-3 minutes all the stored procedures run as expected.

Comment: Try SolarWinds 30 day trial to see if that helps. I have used it in the past with good results.

Comment: are you able to post the execution plan? also, a quick one to try would be putting Option Recompile on it to check your theory on parameter sniffing.

Comment: What is `stored procedure execution log tables`. Is that stored somewhere else before the stored proc is actually called? If so there is probably a delay in the call rather than the stored proc.

Comment: I declare two datetime2 variables one set as the first statement in a proc and the other one at the end and I insert into a table, with other key internal values, as a last statement in each of the procedures.